# Show all values in stacked area charts at given time

Tags: google-visualization

Amazon did a great job with the monitoring in OpsWorks (see screenshot). You can point at any time in any of the area charts and see all values for all charts at that time.

Is it possible to achieve something similar with the Google Visualisation API?

I also have multiple (stacked) area charts and it's a pain to point at each datapoint to get the exact value. Some of them are overlapping or very close together.

[image: Amazon OpsWorks Monitoring Charts]

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger the tooltips in all of the charts at the same time, but if you disable the built-in tooltips, you can achieve something similar by building out your tooltips in HTML and populating them manually in a "onmouseover" event handler:

```
function mouseOverHandler (e) {
    // use e.row, e.column to find data and populate your tooltips
}
function mouseOutHandler (e) {
    // clear the tooltips
}
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'onmouseover', mouseOverHandler);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'onmouseout', mouseOutHandler);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'onmouseover', mouseOverHandler);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'onmouseout', mouseOutHandler);
// etc...
```

In your stacked area chart (assuming you do not replace the tooltips with a custom solution), you can set the `focusTarget` option to `'category'` to make all values at a given x-axis value show up in the tooltip (works only within one chart, not across charts).

Answer (score 0):

You can also cheat by putting all three charts in the same chart element with a little trickery (and some limitations). For instance, you can make the chart like this:

[image: Sample Chart]

Here is the code for that (dummy data):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'used');
  data.addColumn('number', 'cached');
  data.addColumn('number', 'free');
  data.addColumn('number', 'user');
  data.addColumn('number', 'system');
  data.addColumn('number', 'io wait');
  data.addColumn('number', '1 min');
  data.addColumn('number', '5 min');
  data.addColumn('number', '15 min');
  data.addRows([
    [1, {v:0.1, f:'10%'},{v:0.55, f:'45%'},{v:1, f:'45%'},{v:1.01, f:'0.15 GiB'},{v:1.83, f:'12.45 GiB'},{v:1.18, f:'2.7 GiB'},{v:2.28166561658701, f:'28.2%'},{v:2.38024858239246, f:'38.0%'},{v:2.42249842488051, f:'42.2%'}],
    [2, {v:0.2, f:'20%'},{v:0.6, f:'40%'},{v:1, f:'40%'},{v:1.54, f:'8.1 GiB'},{v:1.47, f:'7.05 GiB'},{v:1.77, f:'11.55 GiB'},{v:2.53503269167234, f:'53.5%'},{v:2.74904576834128, f:'74.9%'},{v:2.4119751725877, f:'41.2%'}],
    [3, {v:0.3, f:'30%'},{v:0.65, f:'35%'},{v:1, f:'35%'},{v:1.13, f:'1.95 GiB'},{v:1.15, f:'2.25 GiB'},{v:1.75, f:'11.25 GiB'},{v:2.73464579773048, f:'73.5%'},{v:2.85218912536736, f:'85.2%'},{v:2.80811037750353, f:'80.8%'}],
    [4, {v:0.4, f:'40%'},{v:0.7, f:'30%'},{v:1, f:'30%'},{v:1.27, f:'4.05 GiB'},{v:1.86, f:'12.9 GiB'},{v:1.1, f:'1.5 GiB'},{v:2.86045009159487, f:'86.0%'},{v:2.92068159800651, f:'92.1%'},{v:2.54208355770477, f:'54.2%'}],
    [5, {v:0.5, f:'50%'},{v:0.75, f:'25%'},{v:1, f:'25%'},{v:1.23, f:'3.45 GiB'},{v:1.12, f:'1.8 GiB'},{v:1.88, f:'13.2 GiB'},{v:2.89980619585711, f:'90.0%'},{v:2.8728120099814, f:'87.3%'},{v:2.75583720451997, f:'75.6%'}],
    [6, {v:0.6, f:'60%'},{v:0.8, f:'20%'},{v:1, f:'20%'},{v:1.5, f:'7.5 GiB'},{v:1.78, f:'11.7 GiB'},{v:1.26, f:'3.9 GiB'},{v:2.84876005903125, f:'84.9%'},{v:2.66203284604438, f:'66.2%'},{v:2.63657004427344, f:'63.7%'}],
    [7, {v:0.7, f:'70%'},{v:0.85, f:'15%'},{v:1, f:'15%'},{v:1.91, f:'13.65 GiB'},{v:1.26, f:'3.9 GiB'},{v:1.69, f:'10.35 GiB'},{v:2.71244021344925, f:'71.2%'},{v:2.78368423479417, f:'78.4%'},{v:2.69819140918026, f:'69.8%'}],
    [8, {v:0.8, f:'80%'},{v:0.9, f:'10%'},{v:1, f:'10%'},{v:1.48, f:'7.2 GiB'},{v:1.51, f:'7.65 GiB'},{v:1.41, f:'6.15 GiB'},{v:2.50454251895529, f:'50.5%'},{v:2.59031474717769, f:'59.0%'},{v:2.33299806251049, f:'33.3%'}],
    [9, {v:0.9, f:'90%'},{v:0.95, f:'5%'},{v:1, f:'5%'},{v:1.18, f:'2.7 GiB'},{v:1.53, f:'7.95 GiB'},{v:1.97, f:'14.55 GiB'},{v:2.24595415946281, f:'24.6%'},{v:2.24103507627355, f:'24.1%'},{v:2.22381828511115, f:'22.4%'}],
    [10, {v:1, f:'100%'},{v:1, f:'0%'},{v:1, f:'0%'},{v:1.66, f:'9.9 GiB'},{v:1.61, f:'9.15 GiB'},{v:1.2, f:'3 GiB'},{v:2.1229770797314, f:'12.3%'},{v:2.13527478770454, f:'13.5%'},{v:2.14757249567768, f:'14.8%'}],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    isStacked: false,
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    areaOpacity: 0.0,
    focusTarget: 'category',
    series: { 0: {areaOpacity: 0.5}, 1: {areaOpacity: 0.5}, 2: {areaOpacity: 0.5} },
    vAxis: { ticks: [{v:0, f:""}, {v:0.5, f:"7.5 GiB"}, {v:1, f:"15.0 GiB"}, {v:1.5, f:"50%"}, {v:2, f:"100%"}, {v:2.5, f:"50%"}, {v:3, f:"100%"}, ] }
  });
}
```

Basically, I put all 3 series on the same chart by putting them all as percentages of 1/3rd of the chart. So the first series is from 0-1, the second from 1-2, and the third from 2-3. I then used liberal quantities of `{v:, f:}` notation to make them look like different numbers (for the GiB particularly), and used the `ticks` option to make the axis look like it has 3 scales. Finally, I set `focusTarget: 'category'` so all lines get selected when you mouseover any of them.

You can format colors and even add dummy series to add thicker black lines between the series if you want to make them look more 'distinct'. You can also do some tricky stuff with dummy series and white areas and 100% opacity to potentially add background colors to higher areas. But the general concept is as outlined above, depending on what you are going for, it could work too.